# Add top panel header bar with Streamlit markdown hack

Tags: streamlit

I am currently using streamlit to create a dashboard.  My current page looks like Screenshot A.  I wanted to add a top panel header bar shown in Screenshot B (mockup).  Is there a way i can inject a top panel header bar to my desire style to display information ?

When I inspect the streamlit page, I do see there is a `header` tag with `data-testid=stHeader`.  Wondering if I can inject `div`.  I actually managed to change the `stHeader` style to what I want, but I just do not know how to inject a div into it.  Screenshot C
I just update the style `[data-testid='stHeader']`

### Screenshot A

[image]

### Screenshot B

[image]

### Screenshot C

[image]